# Чи має термін “креативність” синоніми українського походження?

Tags: from-english, терміни, синоніми

***Креативність*** - слово, яке сьогодні у всіх на [вустах](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C&ei=0XDlWs39OqGLmwWeoZnYAQ&start=0&sa=N&biw=1211&bih=928). Його можна зустріти як особисту характеристику, в більшості резюме людей різних професій, і, до речі, не тільки творчих; можна почути з екранів медіа ресурсів, побачити на шпальтах провідних видань. За *креативними* людьми полюють великі компанії, ними захоплюється світове суспільство. А що то за штука така "креативність"? Та чи існують слова відповідники в українській мові?

Для початку непогано було б зрозуміти значення цього терміну.

[Згідно](http://www.eventario.org/news/shcho_take_kreativnst/) ресурсу "Eventario.org":

> **Креативність** - це здатність створювати і знаходити нові оригінальні ідеї, відхиляючись від прийнятих схем мислення успішно вирішувати завдання нестандартним чином. Це бачення проблем під іншим кутом та їх вирішення унікальним способом. Креативне мислення це революційне і творче мислення, що носить конструктивний характер.
>   Креативне мислення має цінність в бізнесі, науці, культурі, мистецтві, політиці, - словом, у всіх динамічних життєвих областях, де розвинена конкуренція. У цьому і полягає її цінність для суспільства.

Вікіпедія [надає](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C) трохи ширше поняття:

> **Креат́ивність** — (*лат. creatio — створення*) — творча, новаторська діяльність[2](http://www.eventario.org/news/shcho_take_kreativnst/); новітній термін, яким окреслюються «творчі здібності індивіда, що характеризуються здатністю до продукування принципово нових ідей і що входять в структуру обдарованості як незалежний фактор»[3](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C). Раніше у літературі використовувався термін «творчі здібності», однак пізніше почав витіснятися мовним запозиченням з англійської мови (creativity, creative). В російській мові, на думку професора І.Мілославського, терміном «креативний» позначається творчість, що «не тільки висуває ідеї, але й доводить їх до конкретного практичного результату. А слово «творчий» (рос. творческий) залишається зі своїм вихідним значенням, що не розрізняє діяльність результативну й, навпаки, безрезультатну.»
>   **Креатив** (англ. Creative) — визначення, що характеризує продукт діяльності людини, створеної способом, що відрізняється від аналогічних, новизною підходу, творчим рішенням. Як правило створюється для привертання уваги, в основному за рахунок шокування, пародіювання, легкості сприйняття, яскравості і високою запам'ятованістю образу. Деякі розуміють під креативом творчість, поставлену на потік. Фактично креатив — це синонім слова «творчість». Називаючи визначені, наприклад, рекламні або художні роботи креативом, в більшості випадку просто намагаються пустити пил в очі новомодним словом.
>   І додає, що цей термін не слід плутати зі *Творчістю* — діяльністью людини, спрямована на створення духовних і матеріальних цінностей.

На Словотворі до слова "креативний" [пропонують](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/kreatyvnyi) наступні варіанти:

> творчий та вигадливий

Що, як ми бачимо з пояснень терміну, не зовсім відповідає значенню.

Пошук "креативності" на [Вікісловнику](https://uk.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?search=%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C&title=%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%86%D1%96%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0:%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%88%D1%83%D0%BA&go=%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8&fulltext=1&searchToken=dlhj17awmg6uvvmuepg729fft) та в [Словнику синонімів на офіційному сайті Української мови](https://ukrainskamova.com/search/?q=%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D1%82&t=0), результатів не дав. Словник українських синонімів на "Синоніми.укр" [теж](https://xn--h1aaldafs6o.xn--j1amh/%D0%9A/%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D1%82) не став у нагоді.

[Практичний словник синонімів української мови](http://chtyvo.org.ua/authors/Karavanskyy_Sviatoslav/Praktychnyi_slovnyk_synonimiv_ukrainskoi_movy_5-te_vyd_2014/) (5-те видання, опрацьоване і доповнене), Львів, Караванського Святослава, будь-яких слів, починаючихся з "креат*(ивний)" не містить.

СУМ-20 надає наступний матеріал:

> **[КРЕАТИ́В](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=192978&page=1421)**, у, ч. Принципово нові ідеї, концепції, нетривіальні творчі рішення, оригінально виконані предмети, які відрізняються від традиційних, загальноприйнятих. *Вони навіщось посипали підлогу (креатив модного куратора, котрий знає, як роздути кошторис!) (О. Забужко); Аналітична розробка і соціальний креатив повинні супроводжувати новітні проекти від самого їх зародження (із журн.); Сучасні технології дають змогу інтернет-гігантам використовувати креатив користувачів без побоювання отримати позов про порушення авторських прав (з газ.)*.
>   **[КРЕАТИ́ВНИЙ](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=192979&page=1421)**, а, е. Пов'язаний з креативом, творчий. *Поки він мобілізовує свої креативні ресурси для зміни реальності, чоловіча частина його армії кидає зброю і збирається додому (В. Кожелянко); Поправка .. здавалася йому [пану Серм'яжному] свіжою і креативною (І. Роздобудько);* // у знач. ім. креати́вний, ного, ч.; креати́вна, ної, ж., Той (та), хто виявляє творчу, новаторську діяльність. *Вона прийшла на телебачення, не маючи жодного досвiду роботи у засобах масової iнформацiї. Почула з телеекрану оголошення – запрошували амбiтних та креативних спробувати себе у ролi телеведучих i тележурналiстiв (Г. Вдовиченко).*

Отже, чи має термін “креативність” та похідні від терміну слова, відповідні синоніми але українського походження?

Answer (score 4):

**Креативний** має всі шанси найближчим часом лишитися таким, без абсолютного синоніма українського походження.

Оскільки **креативність** - новітній термін, то навряд чи можна дібрати йому гідний синонім із того запасу, що маємо, без втрати додаткового смислу.
Ані **художній**, ані **творчий**, ні **оригінальний** не передають духу сучасного поняття **креативний**, бо жодна з цих лексем не має однозначної вказівки на смисл новації. Навіть оригінальний - це своєрідність, але не дух новаторства.

Answer (score 4):

Як на мене, „творчий“ найближче за тлумаченням і, ба, є прямим перекладом.

Але, як бачу, анґлійське „сreative“ має вже, можливо і через вплив заманувок, і нові барви: „нове“, „особливе“, „неподібне“ до чогось.

Якшчо брати з затверджених слів, то, по-моєму, непогано підходить [„новотвір“](http://sum.in.ua/s/novotvir), відси і „новотворчий“.

Answer (score 0):

Серед діаспори, використовуємо слово «Творчість».

Comment: Хм, справді, «творчість <…> 3. Здатність творити, бути творцем» ([СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/tvorchistj)). Хоч в багатьох слово _творчість_ асоціюється в першу чергу з першими двома значеннями («діяльність, спрямована на створення» і «результат такої діяльності»), а не зі здатністю створювати — можливо, через вплив російського «творчество» (?) — але значення «здатність створювати» теж є.

Comment: @Sasha словосполучення "творча людина" асоціюється саме зі здатністю щось створювати. не бачу, чому ні.

Comment: Дякую за ваші відгуки. Шкода що в мене зарас нема більше інформації про це слово.